# ExternalInterface not working in AS3 with Flash 11

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, externalinterface

I'm trying to create a button which will close a flash overlay using javascript and actionscript. I have found on many websites to use ExternalInterface however I cannot seem to get it to work. Any ideas?

Flash AS:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

close_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandlerButton);

function clickHandlerButton(e:MouseEvent):void{
        if(ExternalInterface.available) ExternalInterface.call("hideBanner","");
}
```

Javascript Function:

```
<script>
    function hideBanner(){
        document.getElementById("banner").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

If I add a trace to the MouseEvent then I can confirm that ExternalInterface.available returns true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once I uploaded this to my server it worked but not by opening the html file from my computer into Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

For local access to ExternalInterface you have to add the swf path to the Flash trusted paths, [here](http://jstarrdewar.com/blog/2011/11/08/setting-up-a-trust-file-for-flash-player) is guide for it.

Comment: I just tried this method, but my close button still doesn't work locally.

Comment: you may need to restart your browser in order to Flash Player loads new settings